# .NET Upgrade Hell

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-5, .net-7.0

I have a web application in .NET 5, I want to upgrade it to the latest version of .net.

I have VS 2019 and VS 2022 both installed, I have .NET 7.0 SDK (v7.0.400) installed.

```
PS C:\proj> dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.416 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.316 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.307 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

However, any of proposed ways to upgrade does not seem to be functional.

- From one part, I can't open a .net 5 solution in VS 2022.
  [image]
- from the other, in the VS 2019 the .NET 7 framework is not listed.

[image]
You see the "install other frameworks" options in VS 2019... this one does not work at all, I click on it, it sends me to the SDK site, but I HAVE ALREADY installed .NET 6 and 7, I reinstalled them now, however, is not in the list. What for to do a combobox that has any effect?...

- If I want to use the MS Upgrade Assistant is only installable on VS 2022..., so I can't use it in VS 2019... ((

## What to do, please help?!

- Is there a way to updagrade the .net 5 project to .net 7 via the command line?

Comment: Surely you just need to install support for report projects into VS2022, via an [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, is there any command line tool to upgrade?

Comment: Personally, I update my project by editing the csproj file.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that VS 2022 does not support .NET 5 because you got an error regarding being unable to load .rptproj. AFAIK VS 2022 will support any version of .NET including Framework and Core and you will need to install an extension that adds support for these project types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> from the other, in the VS 2019 the .NET 7 framework is not listed.

Yes, because you need VS 17.4 (i.e. VS 2022) at least to use it with .NET 7 - [.NET 7 release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.md#visual-studio-compatibility)

> From one part, I can't open a .net 5 solution in VS 2022.

VS 2022 supports .NET 5 projects, try enabling it in the individual components tab:

[image]

Also try installing [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022) extension for VS.

Comment: i have .rptproj that seem not compatible with 2022

Comment: is there a command line tool to upgrade? of I am hostage of Visual Studio?

Comment: @serge try using the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022)

Comment: @serge personally I have done all updates manually, but according to docs there is [CLI option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website#upgrade-with-the-cli-tool) via dotnet tools.

Comment: @serge that is for VS 2022 (in the VS installer). VS 2019 does not support .NET 7. It is explained in the answer.

Comment: it seems it not only does not support .net 7, neither .net 6, as is listed in my SDK's console, but finally the problem is solved by installing the extension, thanks! :)